How to find the root cause for ? After installing August 2024 updates KB5041585 on my laptops it's response is very slow, battery drains quickly
Before deploying this update to live environment, I put in the test environment, installed KB5041585 in 2 laptops and tested for 2 weeks. I didn't face any abnormalities in test environment like this dead slow.
So I deployed to live environment more laptops have been installed this update but few laptops reports sluggish slow issue, all these laptops are same spec.
Initially I changed power mode to High performance mode from Balanced mode and restarted, it fixed.
Now I realized this update caused something.
Pls help me to find root cause
I tried uninstall the update, it fixed. And even keeping this update, changing power mode to high performance and restat fixed the problem
